# Persist failed authentication login attempts in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, save, login-attempts

I am using Symfony2 and need to save the failed login attempts to the database.

I have the following methods which I think I should be using:

```
// Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Autentication/AbstractAuthenticationListener.php
onFailure()
onSuccess()
```

But I am not sure how to access the database connection from within them.

How could run a database insert from within these functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define your own failure handler in security.yml

```
        form_login:
            provider:        fos_userbundle
            login_path:      /user/login
            csrf_provider:   form.csrf_provider
            failure_handler: myBundle.login.failure
```

Create a service to handle the failures

```
bundle.login.failure:
    class: 'MyBundle\Services\AuthenticationFailureHandler'
    arguments: ['@kernel']
```

Then build your failure handler:

```
<?php

namespace MyBundle\Services;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;

class AuthenticationFailureHandler extends DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler
{
    public function __construct(HttpKernelInterface $httpKernel)
    {
        $this->httpKernel = $httpKernel;
    }

    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        // the auth just failed :-(
    }
}
```

To save attempts to the database inject your Doctrine manager into the service and persist the attempt from within the onFail method.

Answer (score 1):

Just for logging there is an easy way by using `security.authentication.failure` listener. See [Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/authentication.html#authentication-events). You could use [this blog post](http://www.yfrelicot.com/2016/04/save-your-logs-in-mysql-with-monolog-symfony/) on how to persist logs to the actual database.

```
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Psr\Log\LoggerAwareInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerAwareTrait;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Event\AuthenticationFailureEvent;

class AuthenticationFailureListener implements LoggerAwareInterface
{
    use LoggerAwareTrait;

    public function onFailure(AuthenticationFailureEvent $event)
    {
        $token = $event->getAuthenticationToken();
        $username = $token->getUsername();
        $this->logger->info('Authentication failed', ['username' => $username]);
    }
}
```

And in `services.yml`

```
app.authentication_failure_listener:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\AuthenticationFailureListener
    calls:
        - [setLogger, ['@logger']]
    tags:
        - { name: monolog.logger, channel: security }
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.authentication.failure, method: onFailure }
```

Comment: That link [http://www.yfrelicot.com/2016/04/save-your-logs-in-mysql-with-monolog-symfony/](http://www.yfrelicot.com/2016/04/save-your-logs-in-mysql-with-monolog-symfony/) is broken :/